# How to paginate wordpress [gallery] shortcode?

Tags: wp-query, shortcode, pagination, attachments, gallery

I am using wordpress gallery shortcode [gallery] I was wondering if there is anyway to paginate them without using a plugin.

Comment: Paginate a gallery through the attachment pages or within the post page itself?

Comment: paginate through attachment pages. I mean like show only 30 thumbnails on the page instead of all of it

Comment: Ok, last question - do you need to have separate indexable links for the post/page showing a different page of gallery thumbs? Or could this be done in javascript?

Comment: yes they need separate indexable links for the post/page

Comment: You could simply rewrite the [gallery] shortcode and alter the way it works. An example of how this can be done can be found on the [Roots Theme's cleanup.php](https://github.com/retlehs/roots/blob/master/lib/cleanup.php#L269-L359) file. It's not hard to do and enables you far greater flexibility than any other solution I've seen out there.

Comment: @Ruriko - did you ever get this working as I'm looking for the same thing but unable to find any answeres. TIA

Comment: nope since i'm not a programmer :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've written answer to [How to paginate attachments in a secondary query as gallery?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124191/22534), which can be used for solving this problem. Like @wpmudev-ari said the [gallery] shortcode can be rewritten, or a new shortcode could be created. I explain below - B. - how this can be done. Additionally there is a very simple solution - A. - for the pagination of the shortcode.

## A. Simple solution for paginating [gallery] shortcode

You can achieve pagination by using:

- the `numberposts` and `offset` arguments of the shortcode;
- in conjunction with the `<!--nextpage-->` tag;

like shown below.

**Code:**

```
[gallery numberposts="9"]
<!--nextpage-->
[gallery offset="9" numberposts="9"]
```

This actually doesn't paginate the gallery, it paginates the post containing the gallery - or to be exact the splited gallery. But in some use cases this might just be enough, see the source for more details.

*Source:* [Quick Tip: Paginate Your WordPress Gallery](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-paginate-your-wordpress-gallery--wp-24962)

## B. Paginated by rewriting [gallery] or creating new shortcode

This assumes you want something like this:

```
|---------------------|   
|       content       |  
|       (static)      |  
|---------------------|  
|       gallery       |  
|       (paged)       |  
|---------------------|  
|   << pagelinks >>   |  
|---------------------|
```

### 1. Rewriting the [gallery] shortcode

- Use either a) or b), not both.

#### a)

**Code:**

```
remove_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');
add_shortcode('gallery', 'wpse89462_get_attachment_gallery_shortcode');
```

#### b)

**Code:**

```
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'wpse89462_get_attachment_gallery_shortcode', 10, 2 );
```

### 2. Creating a new shortcode

- If you want to keep the original create a new one.

**Code:**

```
add_shortcode('wpse89462_paginated_attachment_gallery', 'wpse89462_get_attachment_gallery_shortcode');
```

### 3. Shortcode function

- This functions runs if the shortcode is found.
- Explanation for the gallery code can be found at above linked answer.

**Code:**

```
function wpse89462_get_attachment_gallery_shortcode( $output, $attr ) {
    global $post;

    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;

    // We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
    if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
            $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
            if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
                    unset( $attr['orderby'] );
    }

    $html5 = current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'gallery' );
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post ? $post->ID : 0,
        'itemtag'    => $html5 ? 'figure'     : 'dl',
        'icontag'    => $html5 ? 'div'        : 'dt',
        'captiontag' => $html5 ? 'figcaption' : 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'thumbnail',
        'post__in'    => '',
        'post__not_in'    => ''
    ), $attr));

    if ( ! empty( $post__in ) )
        $post__in = explode( ',', $post__in );

    if ( ! empty( $post__not_in ) )
        $post__not_in = explode( ',', $post__not_in );

    $id = intval($id);
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
            $orderby = 'none';

    $output = '';

    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

    $gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
    if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', ! $html5 ) ) {
        $gallery_style = "
         <style type='text/css'>
                #{$selector} {
                       margin: auto;
                }
                #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                        float: {$float};
                        margin-top: 10px;
                        text-align: center;
                        width: {$itemwidth}%;
                 }
                 #{$selector} img {
                        border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
                 }
                 #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                        margin-left: 0;
                 }
                 #{$selector}-pag-nav {
                 }
        </style>";
    }
    $size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
    $gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
    $gallery_nav_div = "<div id='{$selector}-pag-nav' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";

    $gallery_page = (get_query_var('gallery_page')) ? get_query_var('gallery_page') : 1;

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, 
        'order' => $order, 
        'orderby' => $orderby, 
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'inherit', 
        'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
        'post_parent' => $id, 
        'paged' => $gallery_page,
        'post__in'    => $post__in,
        'post__not_in'    => $post__not_in
    ); 
    $gallery = new WP_Query($args);

        if ( $gallery->have_posts() ) :
            $output .= apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );
                    while ( $gallery->have_posts() ) : $gallery->the_post();
                        $output .= wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, $size );
                    endwhile;
            $output .= '</div>';
            $output .= $gallery_nav_div;
                    if ( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
                        $format = 'gallery/image/%#%';
                    } else {
                        $format = '&gallery_page=%#%';
                    }
                    $args = array(
                        'base' => get_permalink( $post->post_parent ) . '%_%',
                        'format' => $format,
                        'current' => $gallery_page,
                        'total' => $gallery->max_num_pages
                    );
                    $output .= paginate_links( $args );
                    wp_reset_postdata();
            $output .= '</div>';
        endif;
    return $output;
}
```

### 4. Additional code

- Take a look at [How to paginate attachments in a secondary query as gallery?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124191/22534) for a explanation

### a) Add a query variable

**Code:**

```
add_filter('init', 'wpse89462_attachment_gallery_add_query_var');
function wpse89462_attachment_gallery_add_query_var() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('gallery_page');
}
```

### b) Rewrite

**Code:**

```
add_filter('init', 'wpse89462_attachment_gallery_add_rewrite_tag_rule');
function wpse89462_attachment_gallery_add_rewrite_tag_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%gallery_page%','([^&]+)');
    // rewrite rules have to be added according to needs
    // below two rules are for two specitic cases
    // /{year}/{month}/{name}/[gallery_page rewrite]
    add_rewrite_rule('([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+)?/gallery/image//?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?year=$matches[1]&month=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&gallery_page=$matches[4]', 'top');
    // /{name}/[gallery_page rewrite]
    add_rewrite_rule('([^/]+)/gallery/image//?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&gallery_page=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
```

Comment: I'm getting blank page. Debug is true but, not showing anything.

Comment: @sakarya There are definitely some issues, variables for CSS missing, I fixed that. Aside from that it does work for me. But I realized it might possibly only work correctly for non-pretty permalinks and the Post Name option for pretty permalinks. I'll take a closer look, when I find the time.

Comment: @sakarya My best guess, because of limited information, is that it is about having the rewrite rule needed for your setup. I have added information and code to the related section of my answer.