# How to paginate attachments in a secondary query as gallery?

Tags: wp-query, pagination, attachments, images, paginate-links

I have this code that shows all images attached to my post-type.
Is there a way to paginate those? I have like 25 pics and I wan't to avoid scroll as much as I can.

Code:

```
<div class="galleries ten columns">
<?php
    $attachments = get_posts( array( 
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'post_mime_type'=>'image',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'post_status' => 'any',
   'post_parent' => $post->ID)
);
if ( $attachments ) {
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, full);     
    $html = '<a class="fancybox" href="'.$src[0].'">';
    $html .= wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'gallery-thumb') .'</a>';
    echo $html;
}
}
?>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you want something like this:

```
|---------------------|   
|       content       |  
|       (static)      |  
|---------------------|  
|       gallery       |  
|       (paged)       |  
|---------------------|  
|   << pagelinks >>   |  
|---------------------|
```

In this setup your the post content stays the same, appears to be static, while the gallery is paged. This means you have the main query, showing you the title, content and so on, and a secondary query, which is responsible for showing you the gallery images. The page links on this page are connected to the secondary loop and do the paging there. To achieve this I suggest using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of `get_posts()`, not only because I don't have a solution for the latter in mind, but also because I think it's generally the better approach. In a first step you have to setup a new query variable, which will be used for the pagination. The function `add_gallery_query_var()` goes into your `functions.php`.

**Code:**

```
    add_filter('init', 'wpse124169_attachment_gallery_add_query_var');
    function wpse124169_attachment_gallery_add_query_var() {
        global $wp;
        $wp->add_query_var('gallery_page');
    }
```

Additionally, if you want pretty permalinks to work with the new query variable, you have to implement a new rewrite rule. For this add the following to your `functions.php`, which makes use of [add_rewrite_tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) and [add_rewrite_rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

**Code:**

```
    add_filter('init', 'wpse124169_attachment_gallery_add_rewrite_tag_rule');
    function wpse124169_attachment_gallery_add_rewrite_tag_rule() {
        add_rewrite_tag('%gallery_page%','([^&]+)');
        add_rewrite_rule('([^/]+)/gallery/image//?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&gallery_page=$matches[2]', 'top');
    }
```

The next step is to create the secondary loop for the gallery. [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) is used to do so, additionally [`paginate_links`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) gives us the possibility to create the links for paging through the gallery. I've decided to create a function for this, so below code goes into the `functions.php`.

**Code:**

```
function wpse124169_get_attachment_gallery() {
    global $post;
    $gallery_page = (get_query_var('gallery_page')) ? get_query_var('gallery_page') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
        'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
        'order' => 'ASC', 
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'inherit', 
        'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
        'post_parent' => $post->ID, 
        'paged' => $gallery_page
    ); 
    $gallery = new WP_Query($args);
        if ( $gallery->have_posts() ) :
            echo '<div class="my_cpt_gallery_paged">';
                    while ( $gallery->have_posts() ) : $gallery->the_post();
                        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, 'medium' );
                    endwhile;
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="my_cpt_gallery_paginate_links">';
                    if ( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
                        $format = 'gallery/image/%#%';
                    } else {
                        $format = '&gallery_page=%#%';
                    }
                    $args = array(
                        'base' => get_permalink( $post->post_parent ) . '%_%',
                        'format' => $format,
                        'current' => $gallery_page,
                        'total' => $gallery->max_num_pages
                    );
                    echo paginate_links( $args );
                    wp_reset_postdata();
            echo '</div>';
        endif;
}
```

As you can see the secondary query uses an extra post object - `$gallery` - and the query variable defined before - `gallery_page` - to enable proper pagination. The latter is used to setup the `format` parameter of `paginate_links()`. We shouldn't forget to reset - `wp_reset_postdata()` - to prevent problems. Of course this is just the secondary loop, not the complete template.

I call the secondary attachment gallery query in my `single.php`, after the main query/loop, via the function `wpse124169_get_attachment_gallery()`. Following above steps you have your paginated attachment gallery set up. I've *tested* this and it's working for me.

---

Below I list the most important information and sources, if you're interested in more details this should get you more then just started.

**Information:**

1. [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
2. [`paginate_links`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)
3. [Class WP/source/add_query_var](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/branches/3.7/wp-includes/class-wp.php)
4. [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)
5. [add_rewrite_tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag)
6. [add_rewrite_rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)
7. [Multiple WP_Query loops with Pagination](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47259/multiple-wp-query-loops-with-pagination)
8. [How to create separate pagination for mutiple loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748699/how-to-create-separate-pagination-for-mutiple-loops)

---

*Optional:*

What it does is, it changes the default link for the first image. Normally it is `http://site.ext/?p=123` or `http://site.ext/post-name/`, the attachment parents permalink. That's ok, it shows you the first image by default. *But* if you want the link for the first image represent the gallery query var in the URL, you have to hook into `paginate_links`. This leads to the link being condtsructed like this `http://site.ext/?p=123&gallery_page=1` or `http://site.ext/post-name/gallery/image/1`. This only applies to the navigation via the link by `paginate_links()`, calling the parent post does only show the according parent permalink. The code would also go into the `functions.php`.

**Code:**

```
add_filter( 'paginate_links', 'wpse124169_attachment_gallery_first_image_link' );
function wpse124169_attachment_gallery_first_image_link( $link ) {
    global $post;
    if ( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
        $gpg_num = substr( strrchr( $link, '/' ), 1 );
    } else {
        $gpg_plk = wp_parse_args($link);
        $gpg_num = $gpg_plk['gallery_page'];
    }
    if ( empty( $gpg_num ) ) {
        if ( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
            $link = get_permalink( $post->post_parent ) . 'gallery/image/1';
        } else {
            $link = get_permalink( $post->post_parent ) . '&gallery_page=1';
        }
    }

    return $link;
}
```

---

**Update:**

This can be used for altering the [gallery] shortcode, like shown here: [How to paginate wordpress [gallery] shortcode?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124835/22534).

Comment: I am really lost with this. My page doesn't show any gallery anymore

Comment: Thanks, I will wait because I really don't understand well PHP and how to construct this kind of functions. The gallery displays now the items and pagination but when I click on next or a number, it gets me to the homepage but with ?gallery_page=2 at the end like this www.homepage.com/?gallery_page=2 no 404's but ...weird.

Comment: Not sure about the problem you're describing, but I gave the updated code a quick test and it's working for me. @CynthiaLara

Comment: With code update I get always link to page 1 of the gallery heh don't really know why

Comment: I really don't know what the problem could be, because I have tested it on two development environments - WP 3.4.2 + 3.7.1 - and had no problems, using the exact same code i posted here. @CynthiaLara

Comment: Thoughtful, well explained answer.  All SO answers should have this level of detail.  Really hope the author accepts as this is an outstanding answer.

Comment: @ChristopherIckes Thanks, appreciate it. Besides that, after reading it again, this is one of my better answers I guess, so it probably would justify accepting it. On the other hand it's more about the fun I have and the things I learn, which is fulfilled and can't be measured in virtual points anyway, so I'm thinking whatever.

Comment: I am extremely sorry I never came back here. I was in other projects and stuff so I forgot about this because I solved with a plugin for fast fix. I will mark this as solved. And please accept my apologies

Comment: @CynthiaLara No worries! Like I said above, none of the things I like about doing this can be measured in virtual points - short, it's all good!