# How to paginate a list of child pages

Tags: pagination, child-pages

I am using the following code to list the child pages of the current page being viewed. But it only outputs the last 5 child pages; i want it to list all pages in blocks of 5 with "next" and "previous" links. Such as it works on normal posts. The code I am using is the following:

```
<?php 
$ancestors = array();
$ancestors = get_ancestors($post->ID,'page');
$parent = (!empty($ancestors)) ? array_pop($ancestors) : $post->ID;
if (!empty($parent)) {
  $kids = new WP_Query(
    array(
      'post_parent'=>$parent,
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
    )
  );
  if ($kids->have_posts()) {
    while ($kids->have_posts()) {
      $kids->the_post();
      echo '<li>' . '<div>' . '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a>' . '<span>' . '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>' . '</span><br/>';
      echo '<div class="extrainfo">';
      echo the_field("info_add");  
      echo '</div>';
      echo '</div></li>';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

The page in question is this one:
http://dedos.info/flavioc/trabalhos/

Now I'm wondering if I should have used Custom Post Types to manage this but now it's too late. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1:

Personally I prefer this, because it gives you more options in the long run. Especially considering other setups involving a secondary query, take a look at my other answer I linked below.

What you need to do is, make use of the `paged` parameter [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) offers. Additionally you have to setup a variable - here `$paged` - representing the pagination. Having this, you can use [`paginate_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) to construct the pagination links.

**Code:**

```
global $post;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$ancestors = array();
$ancestors = get_ancestors($post->ID,'page');
$parent = (!empty($ancestors)) ? array_pop($ancestors) : $post->ID;
if (!empty($parent)) {
    $kids = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_parent'=>$parent,
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
            'paged' => $paged
        )
    );
    if ($kids->have_posts()) {
        while ($kids->have_posts()) {
            $kids->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . '<div>' . '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a>' . '<span>' . '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>' . '</span><br/>';
            echo '<div class="extrainfo">';
            echo the_field("info_add");  
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div></li>';
        }
        if ( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
            $format = 'page/%#%';
        } else {
            $format = '&paged=%#%';
        }
        $args = array(
            'base' => get_permalink( $post->post_parent ) . '%_%',
            'format' => $format,
            'current' => $paged,
            'total' => $kids->max_num_pages
        );
        echo paginate_links( $args );
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

*Note:* untested

For additional options take a look at the according documentations. If you want to paginate a secondary query that is shown in addition to the main query separately to the latter, you have to do a couple more steps, I explained those lately on another [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124191/22534). If you - for example - would like a different rewrite, instead of page, which means you need to use a different query variable then paged, you also could find all the information you need to do this on the question I linked.

### Option 2:

You can get pagination this way too. It still depends on setting up the parameter `paged` and the according variable, see above. If you want to use other pagination link functions wordpress offers, for example [`previous_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link)/[`next_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) or [`posts_nav_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link), this is easier to implement. Key here is temporarily replacing `$wp_query` like shown below, because those functions by default - for more configuration options read the documentations - are accessing this object to generate the pagination links.

**Code:**

```
global $post, $wp_query;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$ancestors = array();
$ancestors = get_ancestors($post->ID,'page');
$parent = (!empty($ancestors)) ? array_pop($ancestors) : $post->ID;
if (!empty($parent)) {
    $kids = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_parent'=>$parent,
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
            'paged' => $paged
        )
    );
    // Put default query object in a temp variable
    $tmp_query = $wp_query;
    // Now wipe it out completely
    $wp_query = null;
    // Re-populate the global with our custom query
    $wp_query = $kids;
    if ($kids->have_posts()) {
        while ($kids->have_posts()) {
            $kids->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . '<div>' . '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a>' . '<span>' . '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>' . '</span><br/>';
            echo '<div class="extrainfo">';
            echo the_field("info_add");  
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div></li>';
        }
        posts_nav_link();
        // Restore original query object
        $wp_query = null;
        $wp_query = $tmp_query;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks A LOT for the reply. it worked.
there's a little catch though; if you could please visit this page http://dedos.info/flavioc/trabalhos and see the pagination links below, you'll see that the links have "absorbed" the last page listed in the url structure. the slug of the last page is getting in front of the /page/2 . i believe it should be simple to fix but i couldn't solve it.

Comment: i see it's in this line `'base' => get_permalink() . '%_%',` 
the get_permalink is causing this issue but i don't know what to replace with.

Comment: I changed the code, try this. @dedos

Comment: PERFECT. thanks a lot. i wish i knew more so i could help out people like this. you saved this morning.

Comment: @something i tried both ways. I am facing strange issue. when i pass order_by to "menu_order" then some posts repeats. Why?

Comment: @DavinderKumar Not sure, don't really know, using the `order_by` parameter shouldn't change a thing, I think.

Comment: but its happening. I will research in free time and let you know why this is happening.

Comment: @something Here is my code. http://i.prntscr.com/3113a0f54369486dad46c1799996e95c.png
If i uncomment the menu_order then results will repeat in pagination. i am wondering how this is happening