# next_image_link Displaying All Images Attac

Tags: gallery

These codes can be used to get the next/previous image, but this code does not limit these images to the gallery.

```
<?php previous_image_link( false, 'Previous' ); ?>
<?php next_image_link( false, 'Next' ); ?>
```

What code would I use to limit the links to the current gallery?

Comment: Can you explain in detail what you want here and where? The only thing I can gather here is that you want to have previous and next image links and that you want to somehow limit them? Thanks!

Comment: Something like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124191/31545)

Comment: Codes that only move users between the next and previous images attached to the current post/page.