# Pagination reset problem

Tags: php

I need a fix for this web page.
The page is attached if you wish to review the code.

The pagination on each tab does not reset to 1 when the user has made a selection. This needs to reset when they click the tab and the pagination show at 1 if there are results to be returned. The user must still be able to access the pages direct by url i.e.:
http://thedemonsjumble.com/pcdev/archives/category/uncategorised/page/3/#latest

Would anyone have any ideas as to how to go about resolving this issue.

Any hep would be appreciated.

Kind regards

Links that change tabs:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="span9 first">

        <ul class="tabs quicktabs-tabs quicktabs-style-nostyle">
              <li >
            <a   style="font-size: 18px !important; font-weight: bold;" class="current" href="#latest"><?php _e( 'Latest Ads', 'agrg' ); ?></a>
        </li>


        <li>
            <a  style="font-size: 18px !important; font-weight: bold; color: #1aaf5d;"class="" href="#free"  ><?php _e( 'Free Ads', 'agrg' ); ?></a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a  style="font-size: 18px !important; font-weight: bold; color: #ff8800;" class=""  href="#wanted"><?php _e( 'Wanted Ads', 'agrg' ); ?></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a   style="font-size: 18px !important; font-weight: bold; color: #ef1207;" class=""  href="#forsale"><?php _e( 'For Sale Ads', 'agrg' ); ?></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a   style="font-size: 18px !important; font-weight: bold; color: #af1b6e;" class=""  href="#swap"><?php _e( 'Swap Ads', 'agrg' ); ?></a>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

One of the Pagination examples:

```
            <!-- Begin wpcrown_pagination-->    
            <?php 



if( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
$wpcrown_pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg('s',get_pagenum_link(1) ) ) . 'page/%#%/#latest', 'paged');

if (empty($x)){

} else{
if( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) ) {
$wpcrown_pagination['add_args'] = array('s'=>get_query_var('s'));
} else{
echo '<div class="pagination">' . paginate_links($wpcrown_pagination) . '</div>';       } 
}
$checker = 1;
?>
            <!-- End wpcrown_pagination-->
```

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you need different `paged` variables for each paged element on the same page. Otherwise, like it happens for you, they will use the same and logically be on the same page.

The codex entry for [`paginate_links()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) gives a basic example for the usage of the `paged` variable. Now for an explanation on how to set up a additional variable for a secondary page-able area take a look at my answer to »
[How to paginate attachments in a secondary query as gallery?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124191/22534)
«, which shows all important steps you will need to do and should get you started - at least. Last but not least, there are surely more Q&A's on here that will help you, you just have to [search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=) them.