# Pagination with a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pagination

I'm having trouble and got stuck on trying to implant pagination inside my custom post type. I've done research from [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination) with little to no luck, I've surfed the already answered questions here, yet I didnt seem to find anything that I could try out in my case. I've checked some tutorials on youtube and got something small started but far from what I actually want :/

First off I'll paste the taxonomy

```
    function porocne_obleke_custom_taxonomies() {
    
    //add new taxonomy hierarchical
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Obleke',
        'singular_name' => 'Obleke',
        'search_items' => 'Search Obleke',
        'all_items' => 'All Obleke',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent Obleke',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Obleke',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Obleke',
        'update_item' => 'Update Obleke',
        'add_new_item' => 'Dodaj Nove Obleke',
        'new_item_name' => 'Dodaj Nov Ime Za Obleke',
        'menu_name' => 'Dodajanje Oblek',
        );
    
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'porocne_obleke' ),
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail',
            'revision',
            'custom-fields',
            'page-attributes',
            'post-formats',),
    );
    
    register_taxonomy('porocne_obleke', array('obleke'), $args);
}
```

After I created the Custom Post Type where I added Pagination on the end of the string that I'm presenting inside the website - it is outside the while loop and after it; BUT when I'm trying it on the [website](http://www.peterp.delavec.si/wordpress/porocne-obleke/) you can see that the "<- previous" is above the picture (I want it under if possible) and its function doesn't work (I currently have 6 posts ready), I set the `'posts_per_page'=> 4` so only 4 are displayed, yet I can not reach the other 2 with pagination function - due to me not knowing how to implement it most probably...

```
function ultimate_shortcode($atts) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'porocne_obleke' => ''
    ), $atts );

  //If category is multiple: 8,9,3
  $categories  = explode(',' , $atts['porocne_obleke']);

    $args = array(
            // 'post_type'     => 'porocne_obleke',
            'post_type'     => 'obleke', //obleke, ne porocne_obleke za post type
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'=> 4,
            'tax_query'     => array( array(
                                'taxonomy'  => 'porocne_obleke',
                                'field'     => 'term_id',
                                'terms'     => $categories
                            ) )
        );

        $string = '';
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
            return false;
        }

        while( $query->have_posts() ){
            $query->the_post();
            $string .= '<div class="row">
                            <div class="column">
                            <th>
                                <span class="track_img">'. get_the_post_thumbnail().'</span>
                                <span class="track_content">'.apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content()).'</span>
                            </th>
                            </div>
                        </div>';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        
        
        
        if ( $query->max_num_pages > 1 && is_page()) {
            $string .= '<nav class="prev-next-post">';
            $string .= '<div class="nav-previous text-left">';
            $string .= get_next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous'), $query->max_num_pages );
            $string .= '</div>';
            $string .= '<div class="nav-previous text-right">';
            $string .= get_previous_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span> Next'));
            $string .= '</div>';
            $string .= '</nav>';
            
        }
        
        return $string;
        
}
```

Is there anyway you could help out?
I'm working inside Child theme, so there is only function.php file inside.

Thanks alot for taking your time!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a shortcode and not the automatically generated archive that will be generated at `/porocne_obleke`? Pagination will work automatically on the default archive, and isn't really designed to be used with secondary queries like this.

Comment: Well the reason is, there are 3 sites that I'm using same "gallery" I'm just calling different category IDs - in which I put the custom post types

Comment: So this is for an embeddable gallery that needs to be paginated?

Comment: See the accepted answer to this similar question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops/249529

Comment: Was about to post the same. @JacobPeattie Shamelessly promoting my answer to [How to paginate attachments in a secondary query as gallery?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/124169/22534), but there definitely is an argument for doing this with ajax anyway.

Comment: In every post there is a picture - and I've arranged the display of  custom posts to be in order as "1-2-3-4" ; since I have more than 4 custom posts I want to use pagination to display the rest of the posts inside this category which I registered in a post type called 'obleke' - I can edit that code in the question if it is needed?